# Indexar db a una nueva ventana

Tags: python, sqlite

estoy intentando hacer una GUI de ABM de personal en python en la cual: En la primera ventana se busca por "id" y por "nombre" en una "x.db". Encontrada la coincidencia y seleccionarla abre otra ventana, y acá es donde tengo el problema. Necesito que traiga desde otra db "y.db" el mismo "id" y "nombre" del que seleccioné en la primera ventana que usa "x.db". Agrego que "y.db" tiene otros datos que necesito que aparezcan en esa nueva ventana. Saludos!

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te invito a hacer el [tour].Me parece que la explicación que das no deja ver claramente el problema que tienes. Quizás falta explicar cómo el código falla o qué es exactamente lo que esperas que pase y no está pasando, o si tienes un mensaje de error, cuál es ese error exactamente y en qué momento ocurre. Para más información lee [ask].

Comment: Hola Claudio, falta mucha información para siquiera poder comentar algo constructivo. Lo primero, falta el error o problema concreto como comenta jachguate, no hace falta todo el código pero si al menos un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Otra información clave que falta si el problema es con la interfaz o cómo pasar información entre ventanas es el framework gráfico: ¿tkinter (tcl/tk), PyGobjects (GTK), PySide/PyQt (QT), Kivy, wxwidgets, flet...?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.